# Looking for comprehensive list of SL4 features supported in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

Can anyone point me to documentation on the SL4 features included in WP7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See ["Features Supported in Silverlight for Windows Phone"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426931%28VS.96%29.aspx) on MSDN.

There's also a "Controls on Windows Phone" section said to contain "a list of the Silverlight 4 controls that are supported in Windows Phone" and referenced from ["Silverlight Application Development for Windows Phone"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462084%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), but it's a dead link as of now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a analysis of the difference of the Silverlight API's with SL4, SL3 and the SL version on the phone: http://firstfloorsoftware.com/blog/the-silverlight-definitive-diff-lists/

Answer (score 1):

Documentation here on differences between WP Silverlight and Regular Silverlight. Class Library coverage also referenced.

[Differences Between Silverlight on Windows and Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426930%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

[Features Supported in Silverlight for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426931%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

[Class Library Support for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470087%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)